# Python setting the sequence from the beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some files as below:
[image]

As a result, I want to have:

```
49111809953_1.txt
78100705693_1.txt
78100705693_2.txt
78100705693_3.txt
```

but now I have:

```
49111809953_1.txt
78100705693_**2**.txt
78100705693_3.txt
78100705693_4.txt
```

Anyone have any idea where I should add something to start counting over if the filename is different?

```
import os
import re

folderPath = r'C:/Users/a/Desktop/file'

fileSequence = 1

if os.path.exists(folderPath):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(folderPath):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folderPath, name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(folderPath, name))
    print(files)


    for ii in files:
        os.rename(ii, folderPath + '/' + str(os.path.basename(ii).split("ODS")[0]) + str(fileSequence) + '.txt')
        fileSequence += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the following unordered list:

```
# After os.listdir()
files = ['C:/Users/a/Desktop/file/78100705693_ODS_2_231711.txt',
         'C:/Users/a/Desktop/file/49111809953_ODS_2_231648.txt',
         'C:/Users/a/Desktop/file/78100705693_ODS_2_231655.txt',
         'C:/Users/a/Desktop/file/78100705693_ODS_2_231702.txt']
```

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` and `pathlib`:

```
from itertools import groupby
import pathlib

for name, grp in groupby(sorted(files)):
    for seq, file in enumerate(grp, 1):
        file = pathlib.Path(file)
        new_name = f"{file.stem.split('_', maxsplit=1)[0]}_{seq}"
        file.rename(file.with_stem(new_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your variable `fileSequence` each time the first part of the file name changes.

This is what I would do, based on your code:

```py
import os
import re

folderPath = r'C:/Users/a/Desktop/file'

if os.path.exists(folderPath):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(folderPath):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folderPath, name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(folderPath, name))

    prefix = None
    for this_file in files:
        current = os.path.basename(this_file).split("ODS")[0]
        if prefix is None or current != prefix:
            prefix = current
            fileSequence = 1
        os.rename(this_file, folderPath + '/' + prefix + str(fileSequence) + '.txt')
        fileSequence += 1
```